# Any ideas why an internal name for column begins with _x0040_Active

Tags: content-query-web-part, internal-name

Content query webpart not picking field value because internal column name appears as _x0040_Active

Comment: It's all sorted. Reason why I added @ infront if the column name

Comment: +1 And the most important is that it cannot be changed afterwards if one screwed the name and then decided to rename with legible latin symbols. It has to be deleted and created anew

Answer (score 4):

Because SharePoint convert special characters in the internal name.

`_x0040_` = @ - [More about mappings for non-alphabetic characters](http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/sharepoint-column-names-internal-name-mappings-for-non-alphabet/)

So that means when that column was created, its title was `@Active`.

Comment: +1 wow, thanks. Already tired of gibberish names in my code even after renaming

Comment: Yes Indeed, noticed it after posting the question. Thanks for your response. Appreciated